# Cannot locate Created By field for Case layout

Tags: opportunity, case, page-layout, list, related-list

For some reason only the Created by Alias is showing up in the layout sort by feature in an Opportunity under cases:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Created By is one of those fields that is not available for related lists. It's not *just* the one related list you've observed, it's *all* related lists. The same is true for the Last Modified By field; only the Last Updated By Alias field is available in its place. I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere, but it seems to be system-wide behavior. If you really need this data on the related list, you can create a formula to display this information.

Comment: Would the formula be created in Process Builder or Workflow, what would you recommend for the formula itself? I'm having a difficult time with the creation process in general.

Comment: You can use just a normal formula (Setup > Customize > Cases > Fields). The formula could be something like `CreatedBy.FirstName & ' ' & CreatedBy.LastName`, or you could use HYPERLINK to have it behave more like a standard lookup field (e.g. click to view the user).